# Sitting and do nothing

Tags: present-tense, present-continuous

Is it correct and grammatical to say:

- I am sitting on a chair now and do nothing.

Or better:

- I am sitting on a chair and doing nothing.

?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, both verbs in such cases must have the same tense. In your case, it's Present Progressive, also known as Present Continuous, because you are speaking of something you are doing now, at current moment. Furthermore, because there are two verbs, you must not repeat the auxiliary verb 'am' before the second verb, so it becomes just 'doing'. Thus, your first sentence is wrong while the second one is totally correct:

> I am sitting on a chair and doing nothing.